# Creating Laravel authorisation policy using something either than 'user->id'

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to create a Laravel Authorisation Policy, however rather than checking the `user->id` I would like to check the related users Business model (like `$user->business()->id`)

I've tried using the following in my OrderPolicy but it does not work.

**OrderPolicy**

```
class OrderPolicy
{
    ....
    public function edit(User $user, Order $order)
    {
        if ($user->business()->id === $order->business_id) {
            return true;
        }
    }    
}
```

**Blade**

```
...
@can('edit', $business->orders())
Edit Link
@endcan
...
```

Could someone show me how I could do this correctly?

Comment: and what is `$business->orders()` ... if that is a relationship method, that doesn't return a Model.

Comment: It is a relationship method, how else should I call the related model? It's not passed into my view from the controller (as it's not used anywhere)

Comment: the link in my answer explains how to use relationships to get the actual models.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `business()` is a relationship method.

`$user->business->id` would be the `id` of the Business model that is related to the user.

May want to check that `->business` isn't null first.

You can also query directly on the relationship if you don't want to load that relationship. `$user->business()->where('id', $order->business_id)->exists()`

[Laravel 5.4 Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Relationship Methods vs Dynamic Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)

Comment: There is definitely a related `business()`, just not sure how to check against that instead of the user->id

Comment: its in my answer

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I know there are records related to the Users' Business in the Orders table. Is there a way I can debug this, I've tried using `Log` in the policy but no lines are printed in my log files. The correct policy is referenced in my `AuthServiceProvider.php`